# I can't get the event from ace.min.js while using require.js in index.html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js

I am a new user in web developing especially using ace,backbone and require scripts. I have to create a web page as MVC/MV* structure by using backbone.js. I have successfully done that. After that I noticed require.js and try to use that. But, there is an event in one of my html template, that needs "ace.min.js". But that will not work after render that template in index.html. Following are the codes and screens of my application :-

**1. index.html**

```
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/ace-fonts.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/ace.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/ace-rtl.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/ace-skins.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/datepicker.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/css/pageslider.css">

<script data-main="js/app" src="js/require.js"></script>
 </head> <body></body> </html>
```

**2. app.js**

```
    require.config({

    baseUrl: 'js/lib',

    paths: {
        //-------------------------------------------
        jquery      :   'jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min',
        underscore  :   'backbone/underscore-min',
        bootstrap   :   'bootstrap/bootstrap.min',
        backbone    :   'backbone/backbone-min',
        ace         :   'ace/ace.min',
        aceElements :   'ace/ace-elements.min',
        aceXtra     :   'ace/ace-extra.min',
        //--------------------------------------------
        app         :   '../app',
        tpl         :   '../tpl'
    },

    map: {
        '*': {
            'app/models/employee': 'app/models/memory/employee'
        }
    },

    shim: {
        'underscore': {
            deps: [ 'jquery'],
            exports: '_'
        },
        'backbone': {
            deps: [ 'jquery','underscore'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        },
        'bootstrap': {
          deps: ['jquery'],
          exports: 'Bootstrap'
        },
        'ace':{
            deps: ['jquery','bootstrap'],
            exports:'Ace'
        },
        'aceElements': {
            deps: ['jquery','bootstrap','ace'],
            exports: 'AceElements'
        },
        'aceXtra': {
            deps: ['jquery','bootstrap','ace'],
            exports: 'AceXtra'
        }
    }
});

    require(['jquery', 'backbone', 'app/router', 'underscore', 'bootstrap', 'ace', 'aceElements', 'aceXtra'], function ($, Backbone, Router, _, Bootstrap, Ace, AceElements, AceXtra) {

    var router = new Router();

    $("body").on("click", ".back-button", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        window.history.back();
    });

    Backbone.history.start();
});
```

**3. router.js**

```
 define(function (require) {

"use strict";

var $           = require('jquery'),
    Backbone    = require('backbone'),
    Ace         = require('ace'),
    PageSlider  = require('app/utils/pageslider'),
    WizardView  = require('app/views/Wizard'),
    slider      = new PageSlider($('')),
    wizardView  = new WizardView();

return Backbone.Router.extend({

    routes: {


            ""                  :       "home",
            "clinicmanage"      :       "ManageClinic",
            "clinicid/:id"      :       "RenderWizard"
    },

    home: function () {

            //this.editor = Ace.edit(wizardView.$el);
            //wizardView.delegateEvents();
            slider.slidePage(wizardView.$el);
            $('body').html(wizardView.$el);
            //slider = new PageSlider($('#wizardcontent'));

    },

    ManageClinic: function(){
        this.home();
        require(["app/views/ClinicManage"],function(Clinic){
            slider.slidePage(new Clinic().$el);
            //$('#wizardcontent').html(new Clinic().$el);
        });
    }

   });

 });
```

**4. Wizard.js**

```
  define(function(require){

"use strict";

var $                   = require('jquery'),
    _                   = require('underscore'),
    Backbone            = require('backbone'),
    Ace                 = require('ace'),
    tpl                 = require('text!tpl/WizardView.html'),
    template            = _.template(tpl);


    return Backbone.View.extend({

       initialize: function(){
           //model

           this.render(); 

       },

       render: function(){
            this.$el.html(template());
            this.data.editor = Ace.edit("editor");
            return this;
       }


    });
});
```

**5. Wizard.html**  -  Template

```
      <div class="navbar navbar-default" id="navbar">

          <div class="navbar-container" id="navbar-container">

            <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
                    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                            <small>
                                    <i class="icon-home"></i>
                                    alloFactor home page
                            </small>
                    </a><!-- /.brand -->
            </div><!-- /.navbar-header -->

            <div class="navbar-header pull-right" role="navigation">
                    <ul class="nav ace-nav">

                            <li class="light-blue">
                                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                                            <img class="nav-user-photo" src="Source/avatars/user.jpg" alt="Jason's Photo" />
                                            <span class="user-info">
                                                    <small>Welcome,</small>

                                            </span>

                                            <i class="icon-caret-down"></i>
                                    </a>

                                    <ul class="user-menu pull-right dropdown-menu dropdown-yellow dropdown-caret dropdown-closer">
                                            <li>
                                                    <a href="#">
                                                            <i class="icon-cog"></i>
                                                            Settings
                                                    </a>
                                            </li>

                                            <li class="divider"></li>

                                            <li>
                                                    <a href="#logout">
                                                            <i class="icon-off"></i>
                                                            Logout
                                                    </a>
                                            </li>
                                    </ul>
                            </li>
                    </ul><!-- /.ace-nav -->
            </div><!-- /.navbar-header -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
     </div>

    <div class="main-container" id="main-container">

    <div class="main-container-inner">


    <a class="menu-toggler" id="menu-toggler" href="#">
        <span class="menu-text"></span>
    </a>

    <div class="sidebar" id="sidebar">

        <script type="text/javascript">
                try{ace.settings.check('sidebar' , 'fixed')}catch(e){}
        </script>

        <ul class="nav nav-list">
            <li>
                <a href="#clinicmanage">
                    <i class="icon-book"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text"> Clinics </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <i class="icon-user"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text"> Users </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="icon-desktop"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text"> Payers </span>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="icon-phone"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text"> Fax </span>
                </a>
            </li>
             <li>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    <i class="icon-dashboard"></i>
                    <span class="menu-text"> Dashboard </span>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul><!-- /.nav-list -->

        <div class="sidebar-collapse" id="sidebar-collapse">
                <i class="icon-double-angle-left" data-icon1="icon-double-angle-left" data-icon2="icon-double-angle-right"></i>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="main-content" id="wizardcontent"></div>

      </div><!-- /.main-container-inner -->

      </div><!-- /.main-container -->
```

**6. Page Screen with error**

[image: Page screen with issue]

Comment: everything else works fine ? I mean, you can use jQuery, bootstrap, etc. ?

Comment: The only `ace.js` that I know is supposed to be a code editor... I wonder what is the relation between this and your `sidebar-collapse`

Comment: There is a collapse button in the left side pane, but I can't get the change while clicking on it. ace.js is a template used for web designing based on bootstrap.js. Is there any problem in my wizard.js ? The variable Ace will get an undefined. Please feel free to update your thoughts.

Comment: Could you give us a link to where you found this library please ?

Comment: Please don't confuse with ace. Actually my issue is "I din't get the event in my view template using backbone.js"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Wizard.js**, use Backbone's View event binding:

```
return Backbone.View.extend({
   events:{
       'click #menu-toggler' : 'toggleMenu'
   },
   initialize: function(){
       //model

       this.render(); 

   },
   render: function(){
        this.$el.html(template());
        this.data.editor = Ace.edit("editor");
        return this;
   },
   toggleMenu: function(e){ /* Do something with menu */ }
});
```

Is this kind of what you're looking for?

Comment: yes. But here in the render function get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined" at the line "this.data.editor = Ace.edit("editor");". I don't know is this an issue with require.js. Please give me your thoughts regarding this ..